# Es posible empaquetar un codigo de python para ejecutar en raspberry

Tags: python

Cordial saludo,

Actualmente tengo un proyecto escrito en python y lo ejecuto en una raspberry, pero como ustedes saben, ese código queda expuesto a que cualquiera lo pueda ver fácilmente; se me vino a la mente una idea, si es posible compilar o empaquetar ese código para que solo un ejecutable de algún tipo que pueda correr desde la raspberry por consola?

PD. Que no sea un EXE por que no lo podría ejecutar en la raspberry.

Gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: Hay varias formas, pero es inútil, al final cualquier persona con acceso al raspberry pi, con tiempo y esfuerzo, puede entender lo que hace el código no importa lo que hagas.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar pyinsatller, aunque como dice @starmiya es cierto, un binario de pyinstaller puede ser decompilado, pero no queda "tan" expuesto a ser leído.. Tendrías que compilarlo desde la raspberry..

Comment: Si señor, pero si nos basamos en eso todo es inútil, hasta los sistemas mas complejos se pueden vulnerar de alguna manera, pero la idea no es poner todo tan fácil, agregarle un poquito de dificultad para que no sea solo conectarme a la raspberry y copiar el código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Archivo zip

Un nivel de protección muy elemental, que quizás te baste, sería hacer uso de una característica poco conocida de python, y es que puede "ejecutar" archivos zip.

Si creas una carpeta, dentro de ella pones tu script pero llamándolo `__main__.py` (y puedes meter también en esta carpeta otros ficheros que puedas `import`ar desde el principal), y luego lo comprimes todo a un archivo `.zip` , y renombras el resultado como `miscript.pyz`, resulta que eso se puede ejecutar con python, simplemente usando `python miscript.pyz`.

Si alguien intenta mirar el contenido de `miscript.pyz` verá aparentemente basura, pues una vez comprimido todo es binario. Ahora bien, si sabe que el fichero es en realidad un zip, puede simplemente descomprimirlo y recuperar todos los ficheros originales.

## Compilación

Como siguiente nivel de protección, puedes compilar tus fuentes y generar bytecode. Este bytecode es binario, por lo que al abrirlo con editor sólo se verá "basura", si bien las cadenas que contuviera tu programa podrían seguir siendo visibles.

Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes el siguiente programa:

```
# Esto es hola.py

import sys

def funcion_saludar(nombre):
    """Esta función construye un saludo para la persona cuyo
    nombre recibe como parámetro"""

    return "Hola {}!".format(nombre)

def main():
    """Función principal del programa"""
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        nombre = "Anónimo"
    else:
        nombre = sys.argv[1]
    print(funcion_saludar(nombre))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Para compilarlo harías:

```
python -OO py_compile hola.py
```

Eso creará una carpeta llamada `__pycache__` y dentro de ella un archivo llamado por ejemplo `hola.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc` (aunque el nombre depende de qué intérprete python estés usando). Si intentas ver el contenido de ese fichero, parece "basura":

```
^V

�r�]�^A^@^@�^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@@^@^@^@s;^@^@^@d^@^@d^A^@l^@^@Z^@^@$
^@^@^@d^A^@j^@^@|^@^@�^A^@S)^BNz^HHola {}!)^A�^Fformat)^A�^Fnombre�^@r^D^@^@^@�$
^@t^A^@j^B^@d^A^@^Y}^@^@t^C^@t^D^@|^@^@�^A^@�^A^@^Ad^@^@S)^CN�^A^@^@^@u^H^@^@^@$
^Ar^L^@^@^@�^H__main__)^Dr      ^@^@^@r^F^@^@^@r^L^@^@^@�^H__name__r^D^@^@^@r^D$
```

Y sin embargo se puede ejecutar normalmente con python:

```
$ python __pycache__/hola.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc
Hola Anónimo!
```

Esto no es un método de protección 100% seguro, pues puede "descompilarse", con herramientas como [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/), que hace un excelente trabajo puesto que a partir del `.pyc` anterior es capaz de reconstruir el siguiente código fuente:

```
import sys

def funcion_saludar(nombre):
    return 'Hola {}!'.format(nombre)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        nombre = 'Anónimo'
    else:
        nombre = sys.argv[1]
    print(funcion_saludar(nombre))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# okay decompiling __pycache__/hola.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc
```

Que es básicamente igual al original, salvo que han desaparecido los comentarios y los *docstrings*.

## Ofuscación

Otra posibilidad es *ofuscar* el código, que significa que el resultado seguirá siendo python "normal" (no binario), pero los nombres de variables se han cambiado por otros, así como los nombres de funciones, y las cadenas se han recodificado,  y en general resulta un programa prácticamente imposible de comprender, aunque sigue funcionando normal.

Una herramienta de ofuscación es por ejemplo [Intensio-Obfuscator](https://github.com/Hnfull/Intensio-Obfuscator), que admite diferentes niveles de ofuscación. Está en estado beta, es difícil de instalar, requiere que el fuente respete ciertas normas de formato... pero para que veas lo que es capaz de hacer, así deja a nuestro `hola.py`:

```
def pxOxsvPEeFeJmdOsCyzZPRQxtouCxyNJ(xmDnGxptkYJljmsgqULjPeTHrCcyzDiJ):
    return "Hola {}!".format(xmDnGxptkYJljmsgqULjPeTHrCcyzDiJ)
def jkRUJhwEliYDSHJgvLgInSOeWklLzofD():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        xmDnGxptkYJljmsgqULjPeTHrCcyzDiJ = "Anónimo"
    else:
        xmDnGxptkYJljmsgqULjPeTHrCcyzDiJ = sys.argv[1]
    print(pxOxsvPEeFeJmdOsCyzZPRQxtouCxyNJ(xmDnGxptkYJljmsgqULjPeTHrCcyzDiJ))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    jkRUJhwEliYDSHJgvLgInSOeWklLzofD()
```

Y este es el nivel mínimo. A otros niveles puede quedar así:

```
YaCbtbrrXIYPORxpboCUwccEFhvMRJjf="""\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x20\x73\x79\x73\x0a\x64\x65\x66\x20\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x69\x6f\x6e\x5f\x73\x61\x6c\x75\x64\x61\x72\x28\x6e\x6f\x6d\x62\x72\x65\x29\x3a\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x22\x48\x6f\x6c\x61\x20\x7b\x7d\x21\x22\x2e\x66\x6f\x72\x6d\x61\x74\x28\x6e\x6f\x6d\x62\x72\x65\x29\x0a\x64\x65\x66\x20\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x28\x29\x3a\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x69\x66\x20\x6c\x65\x6e\x28\x73\x79\x73\x2e\x61\x72\x67\x76\x29\x20\x3d\x3d\x20\x31\x3a\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6e\x6f\x6d\x62\x72\x65\x20\x3d\x20\x22\x41\x6e\xc3b3\x6e\x69\x6d\x6f\x22\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x65\x6c\x73\x65\x3a\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6e\x6f\x6d\x62\x72\x65\x20\x3d\x20\x73\x79\x73\x2e\x61\x72\x67\x76\x5b\x31\x5d\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x69\x6f\x6e\x5f\x73\x61\x6c\x75\x64\x61\x72\x28\x6e\x6f\x6d\x62\x72\x65\x29\x29\x0a\x69\x66\x20\x5f\x5f\x6e\x61\x6d\x65\x5f\x5f\x20\x3d\x3d\x20\x22\x5f\x5f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x5f\x5f\x22\x3a\x0a\x20\x20\x20\x20\x6d\x61\x69\x6e\x28\x29\x0a"""
exec(YaCbtbrrXIYPORxpboCUwccEFhvMRJjf)
```

Aunque no lo parezca, lo anterior es python válido. Prueba a copiarlo y pegarlo en un archivo y después ejecutarlo (no parece manejar muy bien los acentos en la cadena "Anónimo", por algo está en beta, pero fuera de eso funciona).

Otro ofuscador más estable (y menos extremo) es `pyminifier` que puedes instalar via `pip` y hace un trabajo bastante decente:

```
$ pyminifier -O hola.py

import sys
v=len
e=print
i=sys.argv
def s(J):
 return "Hola {}!".format(J)
def b():
 if v(i)==1:
  J="Anónimo"
 else:
  J=i[1]
 e(s(J))
if __name__=="__main__":
 b()
```

Cuanto más largo sea el código mas difícil de entender será el resultado. Si además le pides que comprima el resultado y lo recodifique en base64:

```
$ pyminifier -O --lzma hola.py

import lzma, base64
exec(lzma.decompress(base64.b64decode('/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L+Wj4ACmAJRdADSbSme4Ujxz98E0Cf7oGLdNshZA3TNsLZEFkLph/n9mjAldr2X6JtgdSBivRj9C8HFZojJjaspCVRbYvVGa4vpGxGRDTIcSEQcNDLxCGmJflIYgwvL4VyuFUAK6MEVfo6apgoK1Xne8tpEP6BUEbx0nDgWRayEJwIA/O1kmzhHLognFx2yNG+0r+jzi8sg1yKAas6AAkD4xiUEbI9gAAbABpwEAAJOlgTWxxGf7AgAAAAAEWVo=')))
```

Comment: Hasta ahora e intentado el metodo de ofuscar, me ha funcionado bien con pyobfuscate, pero tengo un problema, estos ofuscadores que encuentro funcionan para un solo archivo y en mi proyecto tengo varios el problema esta en que los ofuscadores cambian el nombre de las clases y cuando otro archivo la va a buscar me sale un error. Por ahora encontre esto: https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/ creo que mirare como funciona.